# mount.cifs fails with mount error(2): No such file or directory - Ubuntu 18.04 and Netapp CIFS

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I am setting up a new Nextcloud v17 server on a new install of Ubuntu 18.04. I am attempting to connect an external storage (CIFs share residing on a NetApp 7-mode filer) to Nextcloud.  That was failing, so I began trying to connect directly with the mount command.  Here is what I have, that is almost working:

Command:

```
mount -v -t cifs //filer.mydomain.com/Projects /mnt/Proj -o credentials=/etc/mycred,vers=2.0,sec=ntlm
```

Output:

```
domain=mydomain.com
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.0.0.30,unc=\\filer.mydomain.com\Projects,vers=2.0,sec=ntlm,user=network_,domain=mydomain.com,pass=********
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Additional details per a request:

```
    root@server:/# smbclient -L myfiler.mydomain.com
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

As far as I can tell, the 'no such file or directory' refers to '//filer.mydomain.com/Projects'.  if I change any of the other file locations int the command it causes a different error message.  I can put anything in place of 'Projects' and the error stays the same.  It appears that the filer.mydomain.com is working as the ip address it returns is correct.

The authentication to the filer must be failing, but I cannot tell why.  The credentials are the same windows domain credentials I used on the original Nextcloud server.

I only dabble in Ubuntu, so don't be afraid to mention what may seem obvious to the experienced. This setup was working for several years on 16.04 and Nextcloud 15.

What should I try or what logs will share more light on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Please post the results of (add to your question) `smbclient -L filer.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Posted above, protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED

Comment: Try installing the `keyutils` package. I've seen bug reports where this package wasn't installed, but it wasn't clear why it was needed.

Comment: I had seen a couple of posts recommending that. It is/was installed and enabled.